# How to rotate the image with two fingers and zoom in/out with pinch gesture in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, gesture

Please provide `any useful tutorial` to handle image with multi-touch user interface

to handle image rotation zoom in/out.

I have already find out something but not so satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial very useful, it does ZOOM & TRANSLATION but not ROTATE
[How to use MulltiTouch in Android](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747)
I suspect you would have to calculate the ACTION_POINTER rotation when it moves & apply the same rotation to the transformation matrix.

Comment: i had performed zoom in/out but for rotating image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894736/rotate-zoom-drag-image-in-android-imageview but this is of no use....i didn't get how to calculate ACTION_POINTER could you please elaborate a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

[This guy](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=rbxccnbzd1) has a 6 article blog about how to implement some form of pinch zoom in Android.