# How to create imageview with zoom and pan functionality?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I created an app that has a small image loaded from URL of a website. I want that when user clicks on that small image it'll show the image in full screen and will also have the ability to zoom and pan that image.

What I've done was showing the image in WebView with built-in zoom controls but the result was ugly. (I've set the layout to wrap_content so no white areas are shown, but it cause the image doesn't zoom dynamically).

Any solution? and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved! For anyone who have the same problem, I've use this library and it works great! http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

Here's a link to [the Github ImageViewZoom page](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom).

Comment: It doesn't support pinching to zoom when the image is in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can build that from scratch or... you can use this library:

http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch

Take a look at the [`PinchImageView`](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/wiki/PinchImageView) class

Comment: Please, give an example on how to use it. I'm not quite familiar with android and how to use external library.

Comment: OK, I've got the library to work. But it still only multi touch zooming, it can't pan the image when you zoomed.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's been updated since 2010... :-/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GestureDetectors.  Google has excellent sample interactiveChart for this, see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/training/InteractiveChart 
and http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html

Comment: Here's an adequate solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578320/how-to-apply-zoom-drag-and-rotation-to-an-image-in-android/47861501#47861501