# Android zoom in and out Image with pinch zoom

Tags: android, mobile, imageview

I am new in Android . i have an image view in which I load image from gallery .
I want the image view to be centre crop and zoomable , I can be able to zoom the image . Zoom should be minimum Of image size . We can zoom more then original size not less .

How can I make it possible ?

Check this I have 2 image views , in which I need to set pictures by scalling properly and that should fit in imageview .

What is happening here is:

Image can be landscap or portraight but It should fit in image view. should start on x=0 and y=0 height should be match parent and width also we can able to scroll left and right to check complete picture and can zoom in and out .

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Image View Pinch Zooming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630373/android-image-view-pinch-zooming)

Comment: you can refer to this http://javapapers.com/android/android-pinch-zoom/

Comment: No i have used that already , zoom is working perfectly but image is not setting properly .