# TouchImageView doesn't show image until after a pinch gesture

Tags: android, touchimageview

I'm using the custom view [`TouchImageView`](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java). However, when I set the bitmap it doesn't show the image unless I do a pinch gesture on it.

```
public class PhotoOverlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String CURRENT_MESSAGE_KEY = "message";

    private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    String currentMessage;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private TouchImageView mImageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_overlay);

        setupToolbar();
        setupImageView();

        currentMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra(CURRENT_MESSAGE_KEY);
        chooseImage();
    }

    private void setupToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle("");
        }
    }

    private void setupImageView() {
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }

    private void chooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            try {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();
                int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512, nh, true);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(scaled);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

I finally found the solution buried [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/issues/135), so I am posting my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap);
```

do

```
mImageView.setZoom(1f);
```

Another option would be to modify the source code to do the same thing since the [`TouchImageView`](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java) class is contained in your project anyway.

Thanks to [this post](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/issues/135#issuecomment-161519018) for the idea.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha, in order to help other people with the same problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thank you! I was pulling my hair out over this one.