# Image Transformation to apply rotation, drag and scaling at same time

Tags: android

I want to apply rotation, drag and scaling on Image at same time. Image drag and Scaling works fine but as soon as I apply rotation Image quality lost. Please give me any example which have rotation, move and scaling on Image at same time and Image quality should not lost after applying  transformation

Comment: Just look into this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578320/how-to-apply-zoom-drag-and-rotation-to-an-image-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578320/how-to-apply-zoom-drag-and-rotation-to-an-image-in-android), I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Look at MapsDemo in the Maps API extension. It implements a smoothed canvas in order to rotate maps.  They do this by turning on filtering in the Paint used to draw the image.

```
private final Paint mSmooth = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
```

Some quality will always be lost in rotation because the mapping from source to destination pixels can be perfect only at the 90 degree points.

BTW, instead of drag I think you mean translation.