# Android Rotate image ontouch

Tags: android, image, rotation, ontouchlistener

i'm working on a piece of code, it scales the image, zoom it and move using onTouchListener. Now i want to rotate the image using touch, following is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
        WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);
        // ...
          int rotation = 25;
          // Dump touch event to log
          dumpEvent(event);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        // Dump touch event to log
        dumpEvent(event);

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                // ...
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                        - start.y);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;

        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(WrapMotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(
                    action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(WrapMotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, WrapMotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

i guess i'm almost there, Can anyone please help me to solve the rotation issue along with the above mentioned features... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got matrix.postTranslate and matrix.postScale.  All you need to add is matrix.postRotate! :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

Check this out:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/

Comment: it contains gestures too, can you please make it more simple

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing the point, you're already using gestures - just simple ones that onTouch can give you and not complex ones like fling.  Just look at the onTouch callback of the onTouchListener.  Try this tutorial for a simple approach http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android

Comment: i tried using 
**newRot = spacing(event);
float r = newRot - d;
matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
**
and this 

**Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.id.imageView);
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,
bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
view.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);**
but none of them worked for me :(

Comment: i've  used this [link](codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android) 
But it gives me force close error when i try to rotate

Comment: hay @Numair can you share the code which was working for you hi have facing same problem.

Comment: @sdevani92 The link has complete project of rotating an image. You can download the project from there.

Comment: Here's a solution I posted earlier.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578320/how-to-apply-zoom-drag-and-rotation-to-an-image-in-android/47861501#47861501