# Rotate image onclick issue

Tags: android, image, onclick, rotation

i'm still working on a piece of code, i want to rotate the image clockwise and counter clockwise using buttons, i tried the following code:

```
case (R.id.clock):
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            matrix.postRotate(getDegreesFromRadians(angle), mid.x, mid.y);

        break;

        case (R.id.anticlock):
            float degrees = 0;
            degrees = degrees-10;
            matrix.postRotate(degrees); 
            break;
```

it is working but not the proper way, first i've to press the button then click on imageview to rotate the image. Any help?

i asked the question here too [Android Rotate image ontouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003125/android-rotate-image-ontouch)
but now i want it using buttons

Comment: this code is incomplete. What happened in `imageview.setOnclickListener()`?

Comment: @ariefbayu you can find my updated ans, i've mentioned the link,

Comment: if that's the case, do you call `view.setImageMatrix(matrix);` in button click?

Comment: @ariefbayu the app crashes as soon as i click the button

Comment: don't take it as-is. Look back at your related questions and initialize `view` the same as you do there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12517/discussion-between-user1296361-and-ariefbayu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I usually do. I create static Util class with this method:

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int degree) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.postRotate(degree);

  return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
}
```

and then, I use it like this:

```
case 21: // ROTATE LEFT
    ImageProcessActivity.processedBitmap = ImageUtil.rotate(ImageProcessActivity.processedBitmap, -90);
    d = new BitmapDrawable(ImageProcessActivity.processedBitmap);
    ImageProcessActivity.selectedImage.setImageDrawable(d);

break;
case 22: // ROTATE RIGHT
    ImageProcessActivity.processedBitmap = ImageUtil.rotate(ImageProcessActivity.processedBitmap, 90);
    d = new BitmapDrawable(ImageProcessActivity.processedBitmap);
    ImageProcessActivity.selectedImage.setImageDrawable(d);
break;
```

You see, in my code, I separate the image that is being displayed with the ImageView. This way, I can easily manipulate the image without the hasle of ImageView. ImageView, as it name explained, is only for viewing the image. Not the source for manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You must notify that your view has changed, so that android renders it egain. Views are not frameRate rendered, so do like this after changing the matrix:

```
yourView.invalidate();
```

Should work