# Android: Skipped frame when drag imageview that overlap another

Tags: android, frame, overlap

I am developing Photo Frame application. I got an issue in this case:
If I have only one imageview, I can drag, rotate, zoom. But when I insert second imageview overlap first imageview, then I drag imageview1 again, it is very lag with logcat: ***The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.***

This is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="250dp"
   android:scaleType="matrix"
   android:src="@drawable/dog" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/image_frame" />
```

**[SOLVED]** I found the problem. That is in the image_frame. It's dimension is too large. After I reduced the dimension, it's ok. Thank all

Comment: what is `@drawable/frame`?  can you add the image or xml to your question?

Comment: @petey: that is only image,  I edited

Comment: can you add the image to your question?

Comment: @petey: for example [link](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/38/1a/7b/381a7bfc8a0ee0db316143f1ddcb5313.png)

Comment: Can you share your Java code as well?

Comment: I follow this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578320/how-to-apply-zoom-drag-and-rotation-to-an-image-in-android  
And it worked.

Comment: Thank guys, I found the problems, see my edited edition