# Scrolling Image in Image View?

Tags: android

I have an image which has a dimension of about 1200x800.. Now I would like to display it in an ImageView in such a way that the image would not scale down to fit the screen of the device but instead it will allow me to swipe to view the other parts of the image. Basically just like in the google's MapView. Is this possible with ImageView or should I use other methods? Thanks for your help.

I tried looking for answers in google but I just can't seem to find the right term for my problem so I always end up with nothing.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894736/rotate-zoom-drag-image-in-android-imageview

Comment: This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058164/android-scrolling-an-imageview