# Android using hand gestures to move and zoom

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, gesture-recognition

I have an image that gets created once a button gets clicked; it gets created in the middle of the canvas, as I set it to do so:

```
if(choosenImage != null) {
     c.drawBitmap(choosenImage, 0, 0, null);
}
```

I want to move and zoom the image using my hand, like drag to to, move it, etc.

How can I do that ? And is that related to `onTouchListener`?

Comment: May this two links help you:

Zoom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out

Move: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is related to OnTouchListener. I think code on the following link will solve your problem:

[Rotate zoom drag image in android imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894736/rotate-zoom-drag-image-in-android-imageview)

Comment: thanks, But I couldn't get it to work. I want when the button is clicked the canvas will draw a drawable ( this is working fine ), and u can move, resize the drawable around the canvas