# Android zoom and rotate image view

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, zooming, scale

Can anyone tell me example of image view which accommodates both zoom and rotate functionality on pinch.

I am not able to find it out.

Comment: Take look at the Following [Stack Post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894736/rotate-zoom-drag-image-in-android-imageview

Comment: it is not rotating smoothly, and many time image is disapered

Answer (score 5):

Check the [photoview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library by Chris Banes.

Usage:

> here is a sample provided which shows how to use the library in a more advanced way, but for completeness, here is all that is required to get PhotoView working:

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

> That's it!

Several methods, such as `photo.setRotationBy(10);` for a rotation and `mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);` for a zoom are provided. More examples, from the sample  include:

```
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) { // Line 71
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_zoom_toggle:
                    mPhotoView.setZoomable(!mPhotoView.isZoomable());
                    item.setTitle(mPhotoView.isZoomable() ? R.string.menu_zoom_disable : R.string.menu_zoom_enable);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_fit_center:
                    mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_fit_start:
                    mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_fit_end:
                    mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_fit_xy:
                    mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_scale_center:
                    mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_scale_center_crop:
                    mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_scale_center_inside:
                    mPhotoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_scale_random_animate:
                case R.id.menu_scale_random:
                    Random r = new Random();

                    float minScale = mPhotoView.getMinimumScale();
                    float maxScale = mPhotoView.getMaximumScale();
                    float randomScale = minScale + (r.nextFloat() * (maxScale - minScale));
                    mPhotoView.setScale(randomScale, item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_scale_random_animate);

                    showToast(String.format(SCALE_TOAST_STRING, randomScale));

                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_matrix_restore:
                    if (mCurrentDisplayMatrix == null)
                        showToast("You need to capture display matrix first");
                    else
                        mPhotoView.setDisplayMatrix(mCurrentDisplayMatrix);
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_matrix_capture:
                    mCurrentDisplayMatrix = new Matrix();
                    mPhotoView.getDisplayMatrix(mCurrentDisplayMatrix);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and

```
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_rotate_10_right:
                    photo.setRotationBy(10);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_rotate_10_left:
                    photo.setRotationBy(-10);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_toggle_automatic_rotation:
                    toggleRotation();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_reset_to_0:
                    photo.setRotationTo(0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_reset_to_90:
                    photo.setRotationTo(90);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_reset_to_180:
                    photo.setRotationTo(180);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_reset_to_270:
                    photo.setRotationTo(270);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

You can see all the samples [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/sample).

Comment: It havnt rotation functionality

Comment: @Dhrupal it does in latest **dev** branch :-)